# Sending multiple commands from Visual Basic to cmd

Tags: vba, cmd, command-line-arguments

So I have batch file that contains series of commands. (about 10) -

I've decided that I would like to create simple gui for this tool - simply one button that would execute commands one after another (when command A is finished command B starts)

Thing is that I do not want to use SendKey method, I am looking for a way that would not even show command prompt window. Is there any way  to achieve this?

I am obviously beginner, so any help is welcome :).

Thank you very much!

This is part of the batch file that I somehow need to "translate" to VBA code.

```
wevtutil epl Application %temp%\Sysinfo\AppLog.evtx
wevtutil epl System %temp%\Sysinfo\SystemLog.evtx
takeown /f %temp%\Sysinfo /r /d y
icacls %temp%\Sysinfo /grant administrators:F /T
 set FILETOZIP=%temp%\Sysinfo


    set TEMPDIR=%temp%\Zip
    rd /s /q %TEMPDIR%
    mkdir %TEMPDIR%
    copy %FILETOZIP% %TEMPDIR%

    echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments > _zipIt.vbs
    echo InputFolder = objArgs(0) >> _zipIt.vbs
    echo ZipFile = objArgs(1) >> _zipIt.vbs
    echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar) >> _zipIt.vbs
    echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >> _zipIt.vbs
    echo Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items >> _zipIt.vbs
    echo objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> _zipIt.vbs
    echo wScript.Sleep 2000 >> _zipIt.vbs

    CScript  _zipIt.vbs  %TEMPDIR%  %userprofile%\Desktop\Systeminfo.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Above runs anything passed on the command line in a hidden window.

& seperates commands on one line

```
cmd /c dir&time /t%date /t%type c:\windows\win.ini&echo hello
```